# React Protected Route issue when children routes refreshing redirect to the parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm currently working on a React application that includes a protected route feature. Here's the scenario: I've wrapped my dashboard within a ProtectedRoute component. However, I've encountered an issue: when I navigate to the settings page and refresh the page, it redirects me back to the dashboard.

Here's the relevant code snippet for better clarity:

```
function App() {
    const router = createBrowserRouter([
        {
            path: "/", // Root path
            element: <ProtectedRoute><Dashboard /></ProtectedRoute>,
            children: [
                {
                    path: "settings",
                    element: <Settings />
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            path: "/login",
            element: <Login />,
        },
    ]);

    return (
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
    )
}
```

And here's the implementation of the ProtectedRoute component:

```
export function ProtectedRoute({ children }) {
    const { user } = useSession();
    if (!user){
        return <Navigate to="/login" replace/>
    } else {
        return children;
    }
}
```

I'd appreciate any insights or suggestions on why this redirection behavior is occurring and how I can resolve it. Thank you for your time and assistance!

Comment: The `user` value is falsey when the page loads and the app mounts. Add some sort of "loading" condition while the (*assumed*) session is checked.